# Atributo CSS com condição em linha de texto

Tags: css, mobile, condição, user-agent

Bom dia, estas linhas fazem aparecer no meu  qual user-agent está sendo utilizado pelo cliente, isso me ajudou com problemas no motor Trident que não interpreta o gradiente no texto e funciona muito bem.

```
var useragent = document.documentElement;
useragent.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
useragent.setAttribute('data-platform', navigator.platform);
```

para que eu coloque o estilo que desejo de acordo com o user-agent eu utilizo no CSS este parâmetro

```
html[data-useragent*='Trident'] section#id.class{}
```

sendo que o "Trident eu posso trocar para qualquer outra coisa assim como o "section#id.class{}", o que desejo agora é que ele verifique se NÃO existe o motor que desejo, quero saber se no user-agent existe o 'Mobile' e tentei com

```
html[data-useragent*!'Mobile']
```

mas não funciona, no caso se '=' (tem) pensei que '!' (não tem) seria o contrario mas não funciona, como eu poderia verificar se não existe com este critério? exemplo de user-agent com e sem Mobile

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: `html:not([data-useragent*='Mobile'])` ?

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira rapaz, exatamente, não conhecia este :not no CSS, nunca vi ninguém utilizando, funcionou, obrigado, agora não preciso mais de aquele monte de javascript para detectar mobile. Este método tem um nome? para eu poder pesquisar mais, saber do que se trata e mais formas de utilizar.

Comment: vou montar uma resposta um pouco mais completa então

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira no caso seriam pseudo classes http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o pseudo-seletor [`:not()`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) do CSS. Ele funciona sempre atrelado à um seletor (`input`, `.minha-classe`, `#essa-div`, `p`, ...) excluindo dele aquilo que está dentro dos parênteses. Existe uma diferença técnica entre *pseudo-classes* e *pseudo-elements*, que pode ser lida [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11701951/4682161). Mas como foge um pouco da pergunta, não vou entrar em detalhes.

Imagine o seguinte `form`, altamente simplificado

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="nome">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <textarea name="Mensagem" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Se fosse a sua intenção deixar todos os campos com 100% de comprimento, exceto o botão `submit`, bastaria

```
textarea, input:not([type="submit"]){
    width: 100%;
}
```

O `:not()` aceita qualquer tipo de seletor. Por exemplo:

```css
p:not(.minha-classe){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p class="minha-classe">2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
```

e até outros pseudo-seletores, como

```css
p:not(:first-of-type){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
```

No seu caso, basta selecionar o `HTML` que não tem o atributo `data-useragent` que contém a ocorrência de *Mobile*. Isso é feito da seguinte maneira

```
html:not([data-useragent*='Mobile'])
```